# d3 force directed graph & svelte reactive statement

Tags: d3.js, svelte

I tried to make a simple d3 force-directed graph with the svelte reactive statement, but apparently, it's not working together.

**1st example**, this is the simplest way I make the graph ([working REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d5bab8c7e2c244e79c7673632dbb9260?version=3.53.1)):

```
<script>
    import * as d3 from 'd3'
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'
    import data from './data.json'

    let svg,
            width = 500,
            height = 400,
            links, nodes
    
    let simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)

</script>

<svg 
         bind:this={svg}
         width={width}
         height={height}
         viewBox="{-width/2} {-height/2} {width} {height}"
         >
    {#each data as node}
        <g class="g-nodes" >
            <circle bind:this={nodes}
                fill="cornflowerblue"
                r="5"
                cx={node.x}
                cy={node.y}
                ></circle>
        </g>
    {/each}
</svg>
```

**2nd example**, I want to add some force with reactive statement to it, let's say forceX, and it doesn't work, until I add `simulation.tick(100)` or any number > 0 inside the .tick() ([working REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0cbf3cb29a0145cabeda08bf18111d2c?version=3.53.1)):

```
<script>
    // the before part is still the same
    
    let simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)

    $: simulation.force("x", d3.forceX(0)) // not working, the circle stay at the initial position
    $: simulation.tick(100) // the force worked, but not animating from the initial position

</script>

<!-- the rest of svg is still the same -->
```

**3rd example**, I tried the .on("tick") with function. The function is fired (I only give a `console.log` to test if the `tick` working.) but I have no idea how to pass the modified data to the `{#each}` block. Looking at the console.log(data) inside the update function, the  `x` and `y` data are changing every tick, but not updating the actual `circle` position. ([working REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/32053e2d8f4549ffb4cec68d44fc9693?version=3.53.1)):

```
<script>
    // the before part is still the same
    
    let simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)

    function update() {
       console.log(data)
       return data // I don't know if it's the correct way, but still not working tho
    }

    $: simulation.force("x", d3.forceX(0))
    $: simulation.on("tick", update)

</script>

<!-- the rest of svg is still the same -->
```

**data.json**

```
[
    {value: 10},
    {value: 12},
    {value: 15},
    {value: 8},
    {value: 7},
    {value: 12},
    {value: 25},
    {value: 20},
    {value: 16},
    {value: 13},
    {value: 5},
    {value: 7},
    {value: 8},
    {value: 10},
    {value: 12},
    {value: 14},
    {value: 24},
    {value: 23},
    {value: 22},
    {value: 11},
    
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to address your problem in step #3 is to declare a `displayData` array, to copy over `data` into `displayData` inside your update function, and to iterate your `#each` block over `displayData`.

`data` being an import variable, you cannot directly reassign to it, and because you cannot reassign to it, it is not reactive and `data` updates do not trigger a re-render.

By assigning `data` to `displayData` in your `update` function (which will run on every tick), you will trigger a re-render of your `#each` block (provided you now iterate over `displayData`).

[Working REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0976bf59d6d94531a9cf3aca42176e90?version=3.53.1)

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Hennes , it's working really well. I encounter some problems with refreshing the simulation, but I already found a solution for that: `simulation.restart().alpha(0.1)` just to adding thins up.